# give copy access to the text of a label in a window

Tags: c#, label

I am developing a application using C#.
I have a window which has a label containing some text.
I want to copy as we copy something from anywhere.
But i cant copy of the label from the window.
How can i do that to copy the text of the label???

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to do this with a label.

You could try doing this with a textbox, to simulate the label and hightlight select.

[TextBox.ReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly.aspx)

> Use the ReadOnly property to specify whether the contents of the
>   TextBox control can be changed. Setting this property to true will
>   prevent users from entering a value or changing the existing value.

and something like

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hello, Select Me";
TextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
TextBox1.BorderStyle = 0;
TextBox1.BackColor = this.BackColor;
TextBox1.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: Relative to the other solutions, this seems like the most direct. 
I like how you still made it look like a label with the BackColor = this.BackColor; and BorderStyle = 0; - Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the blinking cursor?

Comment: I use this approach usually, but for, say, long link text (multi-line, wrapped, etc) the text breaks at "texty" places such as after hyphens which can be confusing. I sometimes prefer displaying as a label then adding an event such as click or double-click to copy to clipboard. Horses for courses.

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to the label to make the label get focus if clicked:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Focus();
}
```

Set the 'KeyPreview' property of the form to 'true' so it will process keys being pressed.  I also added a method to handle the keydown event:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (label1.ContainsFocus && e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        Clipboard.SetText(label1.Text);
}
```

This should work even if the "KeyPreview" property is false. This property is true if the form will receive all key events; false if the currently selected control on the form receives key events. The default is false

Comment: Sorry, need to set "KeyPreview" property of the form to true.

Comment: @DarkenShooter It should work even if the "KeyPreview" property is false.  This property is true if the form will receive all key events; false if the currently selected control on the form receives key events. The default is false.

Answer (score 0):

By default winforms label control doesn't support the feature of selecting text and copying. Instead you can add click event to the label and onclick give focus to the label. And in the form key press event check if label is focused and Ctrl+C is clicked then copy it to click board.

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Focus();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.ContainsFocus && e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
            Clipboard.SetText(label1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, need to set "KeyPreview" property of the form to true.

Comment: my form border style is FixedToolWindow.is that a problem here??

Comment: border style doesnt matter, I tried and its working for me. Is the label added to the form directly?